# Is it possible to store charge in a capacitor with lower voltage to another capacitor with higher voltage?

Tags: analog, power-electronics, boost

[image]

As in the figure above, C1 is charged to V1 volts while C2 is charged up V2 volts which is higher than V1. Is there any circuit that can store all the charge in the C1 to C2? After the process, C1 will be equal to or close to GND and C2 will be equal to or close to V2 + V1 volts. Is it possible?

Comment: "all the charge" - Hmm, just put Maxwell's Demon in the circuit box. Any real circuit will suffer from real efficiency limitations/losses. It's basically a boost converter - discharge into a transformer primary, charge from the secondary, via a diode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some sort of switching circuit.  Examples are a capacitive charge pump, and a boost converter.

Here is the basics of a boost converter:

[image]

When the switch is turned on, the input voltage is applied to the inductor.  That causes the current thru the inductor to ramp up linearly.

You open the switch at some time before the current reaches the saturation level of the inductor.  Now the output voltage minus the input voltage is applied to the inductor in reverse.  This causes the current to ramp down linearly.  However, during this time current is transferred from the input to the output.

When the current gets to zero, the diode will block current trying to flow in reverse thru the inductor back to the input.  If you keep turning the switch on and off, you will keep transferring energy from the input to the output.

Answer (score 3):

If the (?) box is allowed a connection to ground, then the simplest circuit that will do it is an inductor, a switch and a diode.

If the (?) box has only the two connections shown, then no circuit, however complex, can do it.